# How do I uninstall an existing package from the Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
c:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb install foo.apk (Platform 3.1)
137 KB/s (14948 bytes in 0.106s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/foo.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
```

`adb uninstall` looks for a package name and am not sure what it is? How do I find this information so that I can uninstall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ADB uninstall should work.
To get a list of packages installed:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting->Application->Manage Application->

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
adb install -r foo.apk
```

`-r` will allow you to *update/reinstall* the app.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - the poster is looking for a way to find out the name of an installed package.  Your answer assumes that the person already knows that.