# Why this error shows while i uninstall my application from device?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re-installation failed due to different application signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719701/re-installation-failed-due-to-different-application-signatures)

I ran a programs on my android device.Then i uninstall it.And again try to install it.But it shows this error after installing.

```
[2012-09-07 10:29:50 - EXT] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2012-09-07 10:29:50 - EXT] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2012-09-07 10:29:50 - EXT] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.excel' in a shell.
[2012-09-07 10:29:50 - EXT] Launch canceled!
```

Though the application does not exist in my device ,how can i uninstall the application. :(

Comment: This is not duplicate,coz i try this for real device,while the question u referred is for emulator

Comment: THis is not at all duplicate, in other question no one mentioned like `i uninstall it.And again try to install it`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because another application is already installed in your device with same `PackageName` you using in current, So to get through just remove the application which having the same PackageName as yours.

Comment: No, i dont think so, see 'Then i uninstall it.And again try to install it.But it shows this error'.

Comment: You are wrong.I change the package name.it does n't work,show the error i mention

Comment: @MBMJ you can Uninstall app using packagename see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591817/how-do-i-uninstall-an-existing-package-from-the-android-emulator, see your error line-3 1adb uninstall com.excel' which makes some sense, and I'm RIGHT.

Answer (score 0):

Also , this error arrives due to, you already run the application with debug key through connecting your device to eclipse , and try to run the apk with released key in the same real device.

Comment: I  guess this is only the solution ...just put the apk